# How to get wake on lan to work on Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

I have a W7 Home Premium 64 bit laptop, a Sony Vaio F to be more specific it that matters, and I'm trying to set up Wake On Lan on it.

I have it connected to the router using an ethernet cable, and I've following the instructions in this web: http://www.cnetsys.com/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-wol-windows-7

I've followed every single step, tried with my laptop being suspended and hibernated, and I can't make it work. I've rechecked the MAC address of the LAN connector, the external IP of my router, the port number, etc...

I'm sending the magic packets using an Android device (tried 3 different apps) but can't make it to work.

Any ideas of what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS, there is often a setting to accept such packets. 
It is also possible your card does not support WOL.
Also, WOL is not supported on Wireless.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I checked the bios and enabled the WoL setting. Also I'm trying to use it via LAN, my laptop is connected tot he router with an ethernet cable.

Comment: still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it works this way:

1. Laptop's motherboard has to support wake-on-lan feature.
2. The feature should be enabled on BIOS.
3. Laptop should be in shutdown mode.
4. Laptop's power cable should be plugged in.
5. Connected through an ethernet cable to another computer.
6. your network interface card should receive power - i.e. usually an led glows indicating the nic is up, and ready to wake up.

Comment: 1, 2 and 4 are OK in my case. For 3, I tried both in hibernated and suspended, I'll try later in complete shutdown, but for what I've read it should work at least in hibernated mode). For 5, you mean connected to the router? I haven't read anywhere that you need to connect it to another computer... And for 6, I'm not sure what that light would be, how do I find out if the nic has power? I don't see any glowing light in my laptop when it's off, only the power light glows when it's suspended

Answer (score 0):

Try getting wake on LAN to work on your LAN first and then go from there.  Look around for a simple program to do it from another machine on your network. I see from the post that you checked ports but you didn't mention port forwarding specifically, make sure the correct port is forwarded to the correct (ideally static) ip corresponding to your target machine.  Double check your network adapter in device manager, go to properties and make sure wake on magic packet is enabled on the adapter itself.  If you can get WOL to work on your LAN you have at least isolated the problem to your router forwarding the packet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason most wireless network cards do not support WoL over Wi-Fi is because the magic packet is sent to the network card when it's in a low power state, and a laptop (or wireless-only desktop) that isn't authenticated with the network and is completely shut down, has no way to listen for the magic packet, and therefore won't know if one is sent over the network.